# how can i set a specific size for a polygon in 3ds max

Tags: resize, 3ds-max

i'm working on a model in 3ds max and i need to input specific sizes after converting to edible poly.
is there a way to set a specific polygon after selecting it ?

thank you[image]

Comment: could you please be more specific? a screenshot will help too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the uniform scale tool then go to Edit>Transform Type-In. This will allow you to scale the poly on a percentage basis.

The only way I know how match the size of a poly to a specific dimension is to create a new plane with those specific dimensions, position it in an orthographic viewport, turn on edge snap and move your edge loops accordingly until they snap to the edges of the plane.